# Is there a way to create a fake password on Linux that would trigger a specific action?

Tags: encryption, linux, password-management

Think of the worst possibility: Someone has your laptop and you are being coerced into giving them your password.

Can my Linux (I'm thinking of Arch) system be configured in a way that when a specific "fake" password is entered, a script is triggered so that, for example, some files are deleted?

Or maybe, given this wrong password, a fake environment is loaded, so whoever has my laptop can't see the real files?

Comment: Can, yes of course you can.. its open source... should you is a different matter.. you need to hack the password check logic to do so

Comment: @LvB So there's no known software for this? Is this not a common idea/concept? I'm asking for real, because it seems like it would be.

Comment: thats not a questino for this site... maybe ask in StackOverflow itself... (its not a security question)

Comment: FYI, this type of thing is called a [duress code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duress_code). Some burglar systems have that feature. I don't know about computers.

Comment: Possibly useful links: [Do any systems implement a Duress Code?](/q/102619/129883) and [pam_duress](https://github.com/rafket/pam_duress)

Comment: @FireQuacker thank you so much. I didn't know what was called. This will help a lot! pam_duress is exactly what I was looking for :D